# Calculating the Bearing of A(x1,y1) Relative to B(x2,y2) in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, math, navigation, trigonometry

[image]

May I know how I should calculate the bearing of one point relative to another? All the formulas I'm seeing on the Internet are for lat/lon coordinates. I'm working with the Cartesian coordinate system here and am unable to find a solution. Please help!

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the slope of a line between 2 points in the Cartesian plane ?

Comment: I don't but I can find out. How does it help to compute the bearing?

Comment: Because the bearing **is** the slope of the line between your 2 points.  In your picture blue bears 065° from red, and, inevitably, red has the reciprocal bearing from blue.

Comment: How do I get the bearing value from the slope?

Comment: The bearing **is** the slope. The bearing of blue from red **is** the slope of the line from red to blue.  The bearing of red from blue **is** the slope of the line from blue to red.  If you've calculated the slope as, perhaps '4/5' then you have to convert that to an angular measurement. @Axeman's answer tells you how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Use atan2 function (IIRC your objective-c should have it). 
It gives you a result between -PI and PI. You have to map it to 0-360 if you need it.

Comment: I have this at the moment: float bearing = RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(atan2f(y2-y1, x2-x1)); How can I map it to 0-360?

Comment: something like bearing=(atan2f_result >= 0 ? atan2f_result : (2*PI + atan2f_result)) * 360 / (2*PI); should works.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to your question, but if you're getting your points using CLLocationManager, each CLLocation has a course property, which gives you the bearing of your journey for the given point. For the actual math, see Axeman's answer.